# Releasing objective-c member of c++ class

Tags: c++, objective-c, memory-management, destructor, dealloc

I have an objective-c member in c++ class:

```
@interface ObjectiveCClass : UIViewController  {

    int someVarialbe;

}
- (void)someFunction;
- (void)dealloc;

@end

@implementation ObjectiveCClass
- (void)someFunction{
       //Log of someFunction
}
- (void)dealloc {
       //Log line of objective-c dealloc
      [super dealloc];
}
@end

class CPlusPlusClass{
      ObjectiveCClass obj;          // have a objective c member

      CPlusPlusClass(){
           obj = [[ObjectiveCClass alloc] init];
      ~CPlusPlusClass(){
           //Log line of C++ class destructor 
           obj.someFunction; 
           [obj release];
      }
};
```

I'm calling explicitly the release of  objective-c member object from the destructor of the C++ class. I do see the log line of C++ class destructor and the log of some function, but!!!, DONT see the log line of the dealloc.
Should I do something different?

Comment: Your code doesn't show the part where obj gets allocated / retained / autoreleased / whatever.  It's not easy to answer without that.

Comment: @EwanMellor it is done in the constructor. Question was updated

Comment: you are using Manual Reference Counting?

Comment: `ObjectiveCClass obj;` is invalid syntax. Maybe it's `ObjectiveCClass *obj;`?

Comment: Just because you release it doesn't mean it must be deallocated. Something else may have a reference to it.